# Extend pandas Timestamp class

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to extend `pandas` `Timestamp` class by inheriting and adding a new method to the class

```
class T(pd.Timestamp):
      
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  
  def to_unix_epoch(self) -> int:
    return int(self.to_pydatetime().timestamp())

t = T('2012-12-16')
```

However the `t` does not receive the new type but is an instance of `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

I suspected it is somehow related to `__new__()` overriding instance initiating and causing `__init__()` to be skipped

I tried to implement  `__new__()` in my class, but had to forcibly overwrite instances class, I doubt this is the way it was meant to be implemented

```
class T(pd.Timestamp):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.__class__ = cls
        return instance

    def to_unix_epoch(self) -> int:
        return int(self.to_pydatetime().timestamp())
```

The closest I got.

Comment: why are you overriding `__init__` to begin with? You simply call `super().__init__`

Comment: `__init__` being skipped would not cause this. But even if it were skipped, you would see no difference, since you simply call the super class `__init__` anyway

Comment: Anyway, yeah, it seems like the [`__new__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/98e1d2f8cec1593bb8bc6a8dbdd164372286ea09/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L1725) in Timestamp basically calls this function: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/98e1d2f8cec1593bb8bc6a8dbdd164372286ea09/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L135

which always returns a `Timestamp` object. This class doesn't look like it's meant to be extended, so your solution seems as fine as any

Answer (score 1):

So, essentially, if we look at the sourcecode, [`Timestamp.__new__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/98e1d2f8cec1593bb8bc6a8dbdd164372286ea09/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L1725) does a bunch of stuff then returns:

```
return create_timestamp_from_ts(ts.value, ts.dts, ts.tzinfo, ts.fold, ts.creso)
```

If we look at [`create_timestamp_from_ts`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/98e1d2f8cec1593bb8bc6a8dbdd164372286ea09/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L135), we see that it hardcodes a call to `_Timestamp.__new__(Timestamp, ...)`:

```
ts_base = _Timestamp.__new__(Timestamp, pass_year, dts.month,
                             dts.day, dts.hour, dts.min,
                             dts.sec, dts.us, tz, fold=fold)

ts_base._value = value
ts_base.year = dts.year
ts_base.nanosecond = dts.ps // 1000
ts_base._creso = reso

return ts_base
```

so this will always be an instance of `Timestamp`.

So this is not really designed to be extended, so your solution is probably as good as any.

Note,

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Doesn't *do anything*. You are simply calling the superclass initializer with the same arguments that are passed to it. You can simply *remove* this, there is no point to it.